# React: why at a time only single onclick component works while others fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Just started my React learning curve, please feel free to ask for clarifications if I am not able to explain. The question may look long but it's just the code for better understanding.

This is my app.js which uses the router, the problem arises for **profile** path.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <h2>Welcome to jatin</h2>
            <AnonymousUserApi />
            <LoginButton />
            <SignupButton />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/profile">
            <Profile />
            <LoginUserApi />
            <History />
            <LogoutButton />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Once user is authenticated using auth0, user is able to see    but the problem is if i click  component first then history component wont work and if i click **history component** first, loginuserAPi component wont work.

In both the components, I am calling different backend APIs for both the component which sends back data( there is no problem with them).

**Also:- These components can be clicked anytime by the user, it's not like they will be used once.**
Update :- after clicking the first component, when I try to click another component it always shows undefined.
I am seeing cors/preflight issue too, for the second component even though cors is enabled in express

my loginuserAPi component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const LoginUserApi = () => {
  const [orgURL, setorgURL] = useState('');
  const [responseData, setresponseData] = useState('');

  const { getAccessTokenSilently, user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  let token;

  const callSecureApi = async () => {
    try {
      token = await getAccessTokenSilently();

      let decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

      console.log(token);

      const response = await fetch(
        'https://my api endpoint',
        {
          method: 'POST',

          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },

          // sending subclaim as userId to backend Axios request!

          body: JSON.stringify({
            longURL: orgURL,
            userId: decodedToken.payload.sub,
          }),
        }
      );

      const respData = await response.json();
      console.log(respData);

      setresponseData(respData.convertedURL);
      console.log('jatin', responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.error);
    }
  };

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
    if (!orgURL) {
      alert('URL cannot be empty');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="title">Enter your URL</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={orgURL}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setorgURL(e.target.value);
            }}
            className="form-control"
            id="title"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            placeholder="Enter Your URL"
          />
        </div>

        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={callSecureApi}
          className="btn btm-sm btn-success"
        >
          Trimify
        </button>
      </form>

      {orgURL && (
        <div className="mt-5">
          <h6 className="muted">Result</h6>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <p>{responseData}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginUserApi;
```

my history component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const History = () => {
  const [historyOfUser, setHistory] = useState([]);

  const { getAccessTokenSilently, user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  let token;

  const callHistoryApi = async () => {
    try {
      token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
      let decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });
      console.log(token);

      const response = await fetch(
        'https://history-enpoint-api',
        {
          method: 'POST',

          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ userId: decodedToken.payload.sub }),
        }
      );

      const respData = await response.json();
      console.log(respData);

      setHistory(respData.URLS);
      console.log('jatin', historyOfUser);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={callHistoryApi} className="btn btm-sm btn-success">
        History
      </button>

      <div>
        {historyOfUser.map((history) => <div key={history.originalURL}>{history.converted}</div> )}
      </div>
    
    </>
  );

};

export default History;
```

**In short how do multiple components fetching data from the backend can coexist?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have react as frontend which is calling api in the backend, such scenarious will come if api is caching the response.

if the api is protected API WHICH NEEDS SOME KIND OF EXCLUSIVE PERMISSION TO SPECIFIC RESOURCE THEN IF API IS CACHING IT THE RESPONSE FOR another resource it will cause error